# $1.5$-foot radius bicycle wheel spun at $4$ radians per second; how fast is a point on the edge of the wheel moving?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A $1.5$-foot radius bicycle wheel is spun at a speed of $4$ radians per second. How fast is a point on the edge of the wheel moving in feet per second?

Would I just do the following?:

$\frac{4\space\text{rad}}{2\pi}\times2\pi(1.5) $

Comment: $v=\omega\cdot r$, so it seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MattG88 pointed out, $v=\omega \cdot r$, where $v$ is the tangential velocity, $\omega$ is the rotational velocity, and $r$ is the radius.

However, in there is a mistake in your equation. You should have

$\omega =\frac{4}{2\pi}$

$r=1.5$

because $\omega$ is the rate of change in (radian) angle per second, and $r$ is the radius.